# Calculate row-wise maximum

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to create a new column, which equals to the maximum value of all columns of that row.

Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(head(iris))
data[ , Species := NULL]
data

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

I can't really use the `max` function here, because it is going to find the maximum value of all columns, e.g., `data[, max_value := max(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)]`. What I want is something like this:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width max_value
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       5.1
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2       4.9
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       4.7
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       4.6
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       5.0
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       5.4
```

Comment: I feel like a matrix is better storage here, but there's `data[,mymax:=apply(.SD,1,max)]` which coerces to a matrix as an intermediate step, I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I won't vouch for its speed, but this at least avoids coercing to a matrix:

```
data[,mymax:=do.call(pmax,.SD)]
```

Comment: How you get the second max, third or nth max from your answer.

Comment: @Deepesh The approach required for that is quite different, I think. Maybe you will need to search more or post a new question.

Answer (score 8):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
setDF(data) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max = max(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width))

#Source: local data frame [10 x 5]
#Groups: <by row>
#
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width max
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 5.1
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 4.9
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 4.7
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 4.6
#5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2 5.0
#6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 5.4
```

Or as @akrun suggested:

```
setDF(data) %>% mutate(max=pmax(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
```

Which is *much* faster than the `rowwise()` approach:

```
n <- 10e6; nc <- 4; DT <- data.table(replicate(nc,rnorm(n))) 

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  steven = DT %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(V5 = max(V1, V2, V3, V4)),
  frank = DT[,c(.SD,list(do.call(pmax,.SD)))], 
  akrun = DT %>% mutate(V5 = pmax(V1, V2, V3, V4)), times = 25, unit = "relative")
```

[image]

```
#Unit: relative
#   expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
# steven 17.93647 18.024734 17.535764 17.42948 17.484920 16.446384    25   b
#  frank  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000  1.00000  1.000000  1.000000    25  a 
#  akrun  1.00220  1.002281  1.013604  1.00240  1.003089  1.001262    25  a
```

Comment: You could also use `pmax`  i.e. `setDF(data) %>%  mutate(max=pmax(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width))`

Comment: @akrun Yes, by far a better option.

Comment: That plot is pretty neat; could you include the command used to make it? When I remove the `setDT`\ `setDF` (which I don't understand the inclusion of) and the `:=` (to make it comparable to the dplyr lines that don't modify DT), the performance is similar. `n <- 10e6; nc <- 4; DT <- data.table(replicate(nc,rnorm(n))); microbenchmark(frank = DT[,c(.SD,list(do.call(pmax,.SD)))], akrun = DT %>% mutate(V5=pmax(V1, V2, V3, V4)), times = 10);identical(frank,akrun)` Dunno why the result is different

Comment: @Frank ggplot has an autoplot method for microbenchmark objects: `autoplot(mbm)`

Comment: Maybe add the performance of the accepted answer as it is clearly looks very inefficient to me.

Comment: I feel that the `rowwise` answer should be removed.

Comment: Add `na.rm = T` to the `pmax` when the data include `NA`.

Answer (score 6):

use `by=1:nrow(data)` to "group" by rows (which makes each line its own group):

```
data[, max_value:=max(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), by=1:nrow(data)]

data
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width max_value
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       5.1
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2       4.9
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       4.7
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       4.6
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       5.0
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       5.4
```

Comment: This is a smart way to use `by`. Thanks!